# GA4 tracks that the value of purchase revenue is less than the event value

Tags: google-analytics-4, google-datalayer

GA4 tracks that the value of the purchase revenue is less than the event value

Some orders tracked on GA4 have a purchase revenue value less than the event value
I re-ordered these faulty orders the other day and it didn't go wrong
I can't find the reason

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfS2N.png)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but in case anyone else has a look at this question: it's because GA4 does a double conversion of the ecommerce value. First from your supplied currency to USD and then back to your original currency, so JPY > USD > JPY. It's actually in [their documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9796179?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article:%7E:text=Analytics%20performs%20a%20conversion%20at%20the%20moment%20of%20processing%20a%20hit%20for%20non%2DUSD%20currencies%20and%20a%20fresh%20conversion%20on%20that%20figure%20each%20time%20a%20report%20is%20generated):

> Analytics performs a conversion at the moment of processing a hit for
> non-USD currencies and a fresh conversion on that figure each time a
> report is generated.

In your screenshot the ecommerce.currency was set to JPY. GA4 receives the data, converts the value of 17570 JPY to USD. With todays exchange rate it's about 133,89 USD. Then for reporting GA4 converts it back to JPY. Converting 133,89 USD to JPY with todays exchange rate it ends up as 17566,10 JPY.